# Erlang, membase and comet

Tags: erlang, comet, membase

I was wondering if someone had already use this three technologies together. I know Erlang and Comet are widely used, buy I can't find anything related of Comet + Membase or Erlang + Membase. Are them together a bad idea for some reason?

I'm  doing a research using Freemind to map the ideas about these three technologies (Erlang, Membase and Comet). As I'm new to the three I am not certain if they are a good combination.

Basically, the application I have in mind will have many clients ("clients A") sending small amounts of data to the server. The server needs to save this data as fast as possible, and send it on request to another set of clients ("clients B"), where clients B are quite fewer than clients A.

This application is just an idea I have had for a while (nothing new, it's been done already), but I would like to experiment with Erlang and Comet and they seem to fit.

If anyone can provide my with some hints I would appreciate it very much. This is my first question on this site, it my be to open. If it's so, please let me know and I will post it somewhere else.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable question to me, +1. And welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: Thank you! I have used it before, but never as an asker. Only as a silent passerby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For membase, you just need to use any of several memcached clients.  It should work quite well for what you're describing.

Give it a try.  Describe what doesn't work for you.  :)

Comment: (I also wanted to point out that a very important part of membase is written in erlang, so it'll be comfortable near your erlang app)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I found this http://wiki.membase.org/bin/view/Main/Clients#Erlang

When I have something new I will post it.